# How do you find the complexity of an algorithm given the number of computations performed each iteration?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

Say there is an algorithm with input of size n. On the first iteration, it performs n computations, then is left with a problem instance of size floor(n/2) - for the worst case. Now it performs floor(n/2) computations. So, for example, an input of n=25 would see it perform 25+12+6+3+1 computations until an answer is reached, which is 47 total computations. How do you put this into Big O form to find worst case complexity?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to write the corresponding recurrence in a formal manner:

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + n = n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + 1 = 
n(1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ... + 1/n) < 2 n 
=> T(n) = O(n)
```